# Extract the same month in different years mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm developing a logger for my photovoltaic panels, and I've a mysql table with the daily production of last 5 years. I'd like to extract and aggregate the monthly production as for example:

```
jan 2010= x kWh

jan 2011= ...

jan 2012=...

jan 2013=...
```

and so on..
Is there a quick way to accomplish that in mysql-php, without make too much different selects?
Thank you in advance...

Comment: Did you use a temporal type (datetime, timestamp, etc) for your date column?  If not then why not?

Comment: Can you show your table schema ?

Comment: This is the table's schema 'Table DayData (
 TimeStamp int(4) NOT NULL,
 Serial int(4) NOT NULL,
 TotalYield int(8),
 Power int(8),
 PVoutput int(1),
 PRIMARY KEY (TimeStamp, Serial)
);'

Comment: do you have data sample to put it in ?

Comment: Unfortunately not; I have only the current month production :( The previous data production is stored in an other db so I'd like to merge in the new and compare the data of one month (es. jan) across the years. Imagine two fieds, one with a date  and another with daily kW produced ...

Answer (score 0):

If your table has a date field, in which you store daily production you can use a group by on this field, this should work :

```
select DATE_FORMAT(date, "%M-%Y") as monthyear, sum(production)
from production
group by monthyear
order by monthyear
```

Comment: It doesn't work ... Maybe I'm doing something wrong?